# Can timer2 control the pin "oc0" in ATmega32a?

Tags: avr, pwm, timer

On a board the input of a PWM controlled device is tied to the pin `oc0` of an [ATmega32A](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8155-8-bit-microcontroller-avr-atmega32a_datasheet.pdf) and it's not changeable (it's a PCB). Timer0 is busy and can't produce PWM to the `oc0` pin. But timer2 is free.

The problem is that Timer2 can only put a PWM wave on pin `oc2`! 
The microcontroller is ATmega32A (TQFP).

1. Can Timer2 produce it's PWM on oc0 pin?
2. If it can, then how?

Please revise the close votes, it's clear what I am asking now.

Comment: Your question may be very clear to you. But we have no idea of what piece of hardware you are talking about. There are 100's if not 1000's of microcontrollers with timers and PWM generation capability. The one you are using is not the only one!!

Comment: There are dozens of models of AVR microcontrollers with a huge range of capabilities. So no. The tag is also next to useless. Publish the AVR part number you are asking about and I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: Tags are never for supplying information relevant to the question.  -1 for the attitude when asked for additional information.  Closing because we still don't know, as even "AVR" doesn't narrow it down much.

Comment: Question looking pretty good now. Removed my down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OC0 pin hardware of the ATMega32 is closely tied into the timer 0. Likewise the OC2 pin is closely tied into the timer 2. Both the OC0 and OC2 pins are dedicated to specific package pins. I.e the ATMega32 MCU does not have special function peripheral pin routing like some other MCUs have.

If you do not want to re-wire your board then I can think of one possible software solution. You could use the timer 2 to produce the PWM timing but then setup timer 2 to generate an interrupt at the appropriate times. Then in the interrupt service routine you could use software to toggle the port pin that OC0 would normally connect to. It is a kludge solution if it can be made to work. The PWM speed would have to be limited too. So I would really recommend that you make the necessary re-wire and move on to the next issue.